# edit_page or edit-pages for current_user_can()?

Tags: metabox, capabilities

The more I read Wordpress Codex the more often I wonder if tutorials you can find on the net are actually correct. I've found several tutorials about creating metaboxes where user capabilities (when saving the matabox) are being checked like this:

```
if ( 'page' === $_POST['post_type'] ) {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {

       return $post_id;

    }

} elseif ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {

    return $post_id;

}
```

When I was browsing through Codex page on [WP Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#edit_pages) I couldn't find `edit_post` or `edit_page` capability. There were `edit_posts` and `edit_pages` capabilities mentioned on that page. Why there is `edit_post` instead of `edit_posts` used in the bit of code I pasted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find list of capabilities here:
[Roles and Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities)

There is no capability called `edit_post` nor `edit_page`. But...

There is also something called [Meta Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/map_meta_cap).

The capabilities listed on the Capabilities list are global capabilities. So they're saying that user can edit posts or pages. But it doesn't mean that given user can edit given post (for example editors can edit only own posts). This is where meta capabilities are used.

Comment: In other words: Can I use Meta Capability with `current_user_can()` then?

Comment: Yes. Just take a look at description for second param of `current_user_can`: "Recommended when checking meta capabilities such as the capabilities defined in the `map_meta_cap` function i.e 'edit_post', 'edit_others_posts', 'read_post' etc."

Comment: Ah, true! I must have missed that! Thanks for your effort!

Comment: The editor level can edit all posts by default. Author and below can only edit their own with the default capabilities set.